# Is it ok to erase an answer that is extremely vulgar by editing it?

Tags: discussion, editing, spam, offensive

I just came across a spam answer which is extremely vulgar (sexual). I flagged it for moderator attention, and then it occurred to me that I could edit it and erase its contents by blanking it till a moderator gets to look at it. Is this an acceptable thing to do?

Comment: For Stack Exchange, the directive is: no, you shouldn't edit spam or rude/abusive content on which you would raise either of those flags. Please see [answer to: "Should spam posts be edited?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110031/271271)

Comment: OTOH, what you can do is report the post to SmokeDetector in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq). The people in that room can help with reporting it to the bot, if the bot hasn't already detected it. Reporting it to the bot should get extra eyes and flags on the post, which should result in the post being removed substantially faster.

Comment: Both comments above should be answers. ;)

Comment: @Makyen is a representative of Charcoal, as am I; it would be preferable if a community member on this site provided the actual answer. We don't want to give the impression that we are dictating policy without actually participating on the site.

Comment: It may not be policy, but I see nothing wrong with obliterating vulgar content.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If the offensive content is "obliterated", then other users may not appropriately flag it as spam or as offensive.  The *best* thing to do is to flag it and move on.  Spam and offensive get deleted through flagging, and the post itself replaced with a warning about the offensive content (for those that can see deleted content.  *Do not* edit a vulgar, trolling, or spam message to remove the content which will let others act correctly.

Comment: @Xander, if I'm not mistaken, a single "spam" flag will alert a moderator to see what's up, and that moderator will have access to the pre-obliteration state of the offending post, and will be able to delete it. No reason why other users, including those not entitled to flag, should have to see the vulgar content while waiting for users & moderators to act.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But a small number of spam flags will *also* delete a post, and it often happens that the spam flags arrive faster than a moderator.  Please, **do not** edit spam / vulgar posts to remove the spam / vulgarity.  Raise a flag, and trust that the community, automatic systems, and/or moderators will get the job done.

Comment: @Xander, OK, how about this: if I see a vulgar post, I edit out the vulgarity, raise a spam flag, and edit in something along the lines of, "I have edited out vulgarity; please, if you have the necessary privilege, raise a spam flag." That should keep the flags coming, while sparing other users the sight of the vulgarity.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Just raise a flag and move on.  Please.  The automated systems work best if we let them do their jobs.  Flag it as spam, or flag it as abusive, and *move on*.  I do not know how I can be more clear about this.

Comment: @Xander, it's clear what you want users to do. It's not clear to me how this is better than what I propose. How does my proposal interfere with any automated system?

Comment: @Gerry For starters, if I see such a post after the kind of edit you propose, I'd check the edit history before doing anything first. That's less straight forward than seeing a spam post and flagging it, and I'd see whatever vulgar content you've edited out anyway.

Comment: On the other hand, I have seen some stuff that should not be up on our community for more than 1 second, much less minutes while a moderator gets to it (not saying mods are slow or anything, having been a mod of a large subreddit, I know you can't be present every moment of every day and some stuff is up for a little longer than you might like). It's fairly uncommon thankfully, but having that kind of stuff up can be triggering or extremely upsetting for some individuals.

Comment: Moderators cannot get there faster than an automated system which responds to the first flag. Not only does flag-based deletion actually obliterate the text of the post, mark it as "spam or rude or abusive" permanently, and penalize the user that posted it, it feeds a large amount of information into various systems that help prevent more of it happening. You deleting the text, replacing it with something else, doing anything to the body of the post, interferes with that. 1/2 ...

Comment: ... 2/2 You might think you are being helpful in this situation by manually editing spam/rudabus posts - but this is false! You are creating more work, and more difficulty, overall. Please, **just flag and move on**, as Xander said.

Comment: Thanks, @Nij, for engaging with my concerns, rather than just dismissing them. May I ask you one more thing: does the automated system do all that in response to a single flag, or does it take a few flags before the system does all that work?

Comment: It depends on a couple of systems and how they've been set to respond on various triggers. Ping Makyen or triplee, or head to Charcoal and have a look, this will be much more informative than I can be.

Comment: Actually Charcoal as such does not pay attention to, or have any access to information about, your flags. There are several systems that moderators have access to which do need this information, and of course, Stack Exchange the company has some tooling even on top of that.

Comment: @Nij The post which made me ask this question was up for over an hour with $6$ downvotes while apparently no automatic system detected it. This wasn't some random post which contained a curse word, it had a single line with numerous vulgarities that any simple word filter was supposed to catch. I would expect a good automatic system to delete such a post practically instantly. My point is that you are saying we are supposed to leave very triggering posts around for hours for the sake of the learning of a system but no learning was needed here, this was a very simple scenario, an extreme case.

Comment: To repeat Makyen's guidance, you are more than welcome to report it in the Charcoal HQ chat room if you want to escalate a spam or rude/abusive post to a wider audience of content curators across the network.

Comment: *"The post which made me ask this question was up for over an hour with 6 downvotes while apparently no automatic system detected it"* - the majority of those downvotes were applied by the system, one per spam/rudabus flag, and the post was not displayed on any front pages after reaching a (relatively small negative) threshold, so that it didn't get further exposure. That's the system starting to kick in, and wasn't far from stomping down. I'm not saying I like leaving these posts up longer, but please, just follow the instructions given by those who know what does what. @Snaw

Comment: Reporting a post in Charcoal will also typically have us archive it in the metasmoke back-end system, which helps us discover patterns of systemic abuse over time. For a one-off rude post by a user who temporarily lost it, that's probably unimportant, but how would you know whether it's just an isolated incident without this type of analysis and coordination?

Comment: "just follow the instructions given by those who know what does what." @Nij, you are showing a red flag to a bull. I haven't followed the instructions of those who – allegedly – know what does what, since the days of Lyndon Johnson. Question Authority!

Comment: Please, you're not a rebel fighting the power, you're a volunteer on a knowledge-sharing website. If you care about supporting the goals here, use the system here. If you want to do whatever you like, there are better places to be worse at working with the team.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please let me know which situation you believe is preferable:  (1) Normal users use the flags which exist in order to indicate that material posted on the website is offensive or inappropriate.  Because the flags are used, the system learns to better identify such content and can, over time, remove that content more quickly using automated tools.  (2) Normal users simply edit out offensive content, which *might* remove a *particular* example of such content more quickly, but which ultimately denies the automatic systems of the training they require in order to function better.

Comment: Moreover, is such content *really* so important that we have to get our knickers in such a twist over it?  *Most* offensive content is handled pretty quickly.  Downvotes take the content off of the homepage, and spam / offensive / rude / abusive flags are quite effective at removing bad content.  In the comments it is mentioned that a particular post was on the site for 6 hours---this is an outlier; in my experience, nearly *all* such posts are automatically deleted in timeframes measured in minutes.

Comment: @XanderHenderson How many flags for offensive/rude does it take until a post is deleted (till a moderator looks at it)? It doesn't seem like it should take much more than 1 such flag. In an ideal world if it is a false positive then the moderator can bring the post back up and also suspend the flagging privilege of the offending flagger. If such 'super flagging' capability is still too powerful then it can be given to only users with say over 500 rep or it may still require 2 flags. But anything more than 2 seems odd. I realize this may not be the choice of the moderators at MSE. Just curious.

Comment: @Snaw The details of how the algorithms work are intentionally kept somewhat secretive (as a security-through-obscurity measure---whatever you think of this approach to security).  However, please think through your assertion that it should only take one flag:  this would empower any troll to delete just about anything through flagging it.  Clearly, you want more than one flag.  In any event, you seem to concede this point, and understand that there needs to be some level of collective action take.  Now you are just haggling over what the *actual* thresholds should be.

Comment: @XanderHenderson It's just that something seems odd to me. I think that even 1 flag is enough-- said troll would lose their flagging rights afterwards and it would only be given to a user with sufficient rep in the first place. A legitimate post being deleted for 2 hours till a moderator looks at it is better than extremely violent content staying around for 2 hours. To prevent a random troll from doing some limited damage you can require 2 flags. Given how long it took to delete the post in question I guess it takes more than that. I understand that this is secretive. Just sharing my opinion.

Comment: @Snaw (1) You may not be aware of this, but there are a *lot* of trolls who have found very efficient ways to quickly earn enough reputation to gain basic privileges (such as flagging), and use that to troll the site.  It is generally best not to give *one* person the power to make unilateral decisions.  (2) You assume that such abuses would be noticed.  Suppose that a user decides to delete a bunch of 5 year old answers---it is very likely that they could do so without anyone noticing.  A troll might very easily cause a lot of damage without anyone noting it.

Comment: (3) You further seem to assume that no one has ever asked the questions you are asking before.  I was not here at the beginning, but I expect that these thresholds have been discussed at length internally, and that there are at least some data which back up the current approach.  @Makyen may be able to provide more information on this, as their knowledge of the "bad post" detection systems are second-to-none.  (4) You have not answered my question---is such content *really* so important?  What *actual* damage is done by ensuring that some due process can occur before deletion?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for the information. Regarding (2), in this hypothetical scenario where 1 or 2 super-flags is all that is needed to delete a post, all such super-flags would be reviewed by a moderator as soon as possible. For (3): I respect the consensus of the community. If someone has a link to such discussions I'd be very interested. Most importantly, for your question in (4): yes, sometimes it *really* can be bad and can cause *actual* damage. This site is frequented by minors. Even if it wasn't for that, some posts constitute verbal sexual abuse. This can be very serious.

Comment: That's one of the reasons there is [an age limit in the terms of service.](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age) You also seem to think the moderators are idempotent and idempresent; they generally are not. Flag limits etc are set network-wide (though with some mechanisms for individual sites to tweak them); these things are discussed on [meta.se] though I doubt you can find a single source of truth there.

Comment: @trip, "idempotent and idempresent"? I think the words you were looking for are *omnipotent* and *omnipresent*.

Comment: @Xander, I think if you had explained the bit about the system learning to remove content earlier, we might have saved several days of discussion. Such explanations are always more convincing than "just do what we tell you to do."

Comment: Yeah, only having my morning coffee now (-:

Comment: @tripleee That age limit is 13.

Comment: I guess the reasonig is something like, if they are old enough to watch _The Walking Dead_ they are old enough to read random graffiti.

Comment: @tripleee When one directly addresses a member of the community with offensive sexual words it is more than random graffiti, it can be as much as verbal sexual abuse. This may be quite offensive even for adults, surely for 13 year olds. This is why I can't see how the current flagging policy makes sense. Personally I would prefer a post being accidentally suspended once in a while rather than an offensive post staying on for any longer than it should stay. I realize though that this is not the place for this discussion and that the stack exchange meta site is the right place for it instead.

Comment: I'm probably more jaded than I should be, but you seem to be asking about quite the exceptional case. You have been offered two escalation paths instead of your proposed solution, but I'll offer two more: if something is so bad that you feel it needs to be removed immediately, and Charcoal and the site mods don't seem to help, try the "contact us" link in the site footer (usually not a very swift process, but probably worth the effort if you really are looking at something which could warrant legal action), and posting on [meta.se]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From the comments: No. Instead, flag it as *rude or abusive* and move on.

Answer (score 10):

Rude/abuse/spam deletions are causing -100 rep loss to the OP and the post content is defaced. People having access to the deleted content (OP + mods + 10k+ users) can still see it, but even they need an extra click to see its edit history.

[image]

These deletions can be caused by at least 6 spam/rude/abusive flags, and possibly also by mod. The deletion will happen as if it had been done by the community bot. Mods get notified and they decide, what to do to the perpetrator. The most likely consequence is either suspension, or account destruction (if it is a low-rep spammer).

Defacing the post would remove evidence. Vote down, flag and wait. If you get back your lost rep, you know that it is done. Normally it happens quickly.

Comment: "Defacing the post would remove evidence." Is that right? Deleting the offensive material would cause it to take some extra clicks to see the evidence, but the evidence would still be there, wouldn't it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Mods are enough smart to check also the edit history, but anybody can flag from 15 rep, and they might be not.

Comment: Thanks. That's why I suggested, in one of the comments some days ago, that a user  flagging and deleting offensive content would also leave a note to the effect that offensive content had been edited out and that other users could see the edit history if they cared to.

Comment: But comments are not reliable; they too can be deleted at somebody's whim.

Comment: @trip, I think you misunderstand me. On 10 Feb, at 22:59, I posted the following in a comment on this page: "if I see a vulgar post, I edit out the vulgarity, raise a spam flag, and edit in something along the lines of, "I have edited out vulgarity; please, if you have the necessary privilege, raise a spam flag." That should keep the flags coming, while sparing other users the sight of the vulgarity." Anyway, there aren't that many actors authorized to delete comments, and who would delete a useful comment? I really don't see what you're getting at.

Comment: And if you intend a comment for me, @trip, please use the at-sign notification technique, as I have done here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Many people have given you a lot of good reasons why it is best to let the automatic systems do their job.  If you want to continue to insist that you know better, do what you like.  The fact is, however, that if you choose to edit vulgar posts (rather than just flag and move on), you increase the likelihood that a post will be mishandled.

Comment: @Xander, yes, people have given me good reasons. Other people have given me bad reasons, or no reasons at all. I was happy to let things be, until peterh posted what I consider to be a misleading answer, which tripleee compounded by failing to understand my proposal. I'm happy to accept the good reasons, but not to let the bad ones just slide by.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Here opinions are imho different. If I would see a vulgar post with also long-lasting content, I would edit it out (and then I would vote the current version of the post). Many people, particularly on the SO, thinks that anything interpreted even a little bit vulgary should deserve close-down-del, -100 rep and suspension. Possibly they would also shot the perpetrator in the head.

Comment: Your comment seems inconsistent, peterh, with your answer, "Defacing the post would remove evidence. Vote down, flag and wait."

Comment: @GerryMyerson If the content is an useful post, then just editing out the bad part is obviously much better. I think it is pretty rational.

Comment: Most of the other people taking part in this discussion disagree with you, peterh, and they have presented some pretty good reasons for not "editing out the bad part" before flagging. Or are you suggesting not flagging at all, when someone posts truly offensive matter?

Comment: @GerryMyerson 1) Vulgar content with insult: I edit out the vulgar part. I do not cast flag (but possible others already did it at the time - and, if the 6 flag for the -100 did not happen, then a mod will see it soon). If the content, after the edit, becomes upvote-deserving, then I also vote it up. 2) If it is just vulgar or spam --> down + flag. | This is what I do, I remove what is not okay and leave what is.